# Can we Clone Motherboard or find Registration Key?

Tags: motherboard, clone

I recently found out that the main software that we use in our shop is registered on the motherboard.  The company that developed the software was sold and the new owner is saying that they do not have the registration key for our version (which was only one year prior to the sale).  We are operating on an old computer with XP and need to get the software transferred to a new computer before it crashes.  Is there some way to find the registration key or clone the motherboard data so that we can move the software?

Comment: "Can we Clone Motherboard or find Registration Key?" - No; It's very unlikely the license key is actually stored on the motherboard.  To my knowledge, only the Windows license key is stored in the ACPI table on a motherboard, and that's only in the case, of OEM hardware.

Answer (score 2):

First, it is highly unlikely that anything is stored on the motherboard,
unless that company was in the chip-making business.
It is far more likely that some setting enables this software.

Second, it is quite possible that software that ran on Windows XP will not run
on newer hardware or Windows version, so trying to install the software
on a new computer (if you have the installation media) may not succeed.

The solution would be to do
[Physical-to-Virtual (P2V)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical-to-Virtual),
meaning virtualize the entire XP computer into a virtual machine that can be
run on any hardware or operating system.

There are several possibilities, so choose the one that works for you:

- [disk2vhd](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415.aspx)
  from SysInternals.
- [Physical To Virtual (P2V) using VirtualBox](https://www.linux.org/threads/physical-to-virtual-p2v-using-virtualbox.10928/)
- [VMware vCenter Converter](https://www.vmware.com/products/converter.html)

Answer (score 0):

Registration key is almost certainly not stored on the motherboard. Most likely the software collects some information from your hardware during registration, such as serial number of processor, motherboard, hard disk, MAC address of network card etc.

This information is then stored on disk, likely in an encrypted or digitally signed format so that you cannot modify it. It could also be sent over the internet and stored on company servers, for example.

Whenever you run the program, it compares the serial numbers from the hardware to what was written to the disk during registration (or against servers on the internet). This means that if you copy the program onto a different hardware, it will detect different serial numbers it and will not run.

Unfortunately, this kind of protection is extremely problematic as it is based on assumption that your hardware will work forever. There is no hardware that will work forever, which means that even in legal cases (when you are not conterfeiting anything) you might still have to pay for new activation. Worse still, if the company goes out of business, you find yourself in a position where sooner or later something will break and you will lose everything.

It is absolutely no surprise that this company went out of business.

There is no simple solution for that. If your data is extremely valuable, you might want to hire a hacker that will disable the protection in the program. This is however expensive, complicated, probably illegal, and is not guaranteed to work. If a program is/was popular, you might be even able to find the crack on the internet, but again - no guarantee that it will work.

Changing serial numbers of the hardware is even worse - while theoretically not impossible, it is very much unrealistic.

Answer (score -1):

You can use product key finders like https://www.magicaljellybean.com/keyfinder/ or alternatives, to find the key for Windows. Windows XP should support this, but newer Windows may not. I remember I used to use this back in the day, though now key registration is a bit more complicated and uses Internet verification.

You can also image or clone the hard drive using many methods such as `dd` , clonezilla, or others. But if you're putting this clone into any computer with different specs (or even  a different motherboard) Windows may fail to boot entirely. My personal experiences have led me to recommend you to clean install Windows on the new PC but it might not be strictly necessary.

EDIT: Sorry, I see you're talking about the software rather than Windows, my apologies. This is entirely up to the software itself, but product key finders may be able to recover it. I suggest you contact technical support for the software and ask them about transferring licenses.

Comment: " the software was sold and the new owner is saying that they do not have the registration key for our version " They are not going to help.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  The new company told me that they do not have the key for the software version that I have, which was only the version prior to their purchase.  They did not have any suggestions on what I can do.  The previous owner is still around and I may contact him for help.  If that fails I will try the physical to virtual steps.